# Parse json events from azure time series insights with C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, time-series, azure-timeseries-insights

Are there any standards for how to parse the json response from Azure Time Series API? It looks a lot like JSON schemas, but not quite.

It's hard to find any guidelines from Microsoft on how to handle the parsing. Deserializing with JSON.NET is also tricky because property names can consist of dots when a nested data object has been sent.

Sample json:

```
{
    {
        "warnings": [],
        "events": [
            {
                "schema": {
                    "rid": 0,
                    "$esn": "Test",
                    "properties": [
                        {
                            "name": "a.identifier",
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "a.number",
                            "type": "Double"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "descr",
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "$ts": "2018-01-21T22:57:00.095Z",
                "values": [
                    "test",
                    2.1,
                    "fdsasf"
                ]
            },
            {
                "schemaRid": 0,
                "$ts": "2018-01-21T22:57:00.095Z",
                "values": [
                    "test2",
                    223,
                    "gjmnsfg"
                ]
            },
            {
                "schemaRid": 0,
                "$ts": "2018-01-21T22:57:00.095Z",
                "values": [
                    "test3",
                    43.5,
                    "sasd"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want to deserialize above json?

Comment: I was able to find on GitHub the [json schema](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification/timeseriesinsights/resource-manager/Microsoft.TimeSeriesInsights/stable/2017-11-15) and [some examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification/timeseriesinsights/resource-manager/Microsoft.TimeSeriesInsights/stable/2017-11-15/examples), I hope this helps

Comment: Also, have you seen the [Azure Time Series Insights query syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-reference-query-syntax) and the [Azure Time Series Insights Query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-reference-queryapi)?

Comment: @RuiJarimba, the "json schema and some examples" you provided are for TSI template deployment, not for data query responses. However, the  [Azure Time Series Insights Query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-reference-queryapi) does provide some insights, but they are far from enough

Answer (score 1):

I have to disappoint you, that I was also looking for this info, but until now didn't find anything. Indeed, the only on-topic info provided by MSFT that I can see, is the link provided by Rui Jarimba, [Azure Time Series Insights Query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-reference-queryapi). But that is just nothing.

The best you can do is just explore it yourself.

Nevertheless, I have few useful things to mention here:

- the generated "schema" object is case-sensitive on the properties' names returned in each event. So if you have "timestamp" and "Timestamp", you will end-up with separate schemas for these events (the `schemaRid` will be different)
- there is a [GitHub sample "Hello, World" project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-Time-Series-Insights/tree/master/C-%20Hello%20World%20App%20Sample) that provides some query examples along with result parsing which could be useful for some basic references

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Andrew, a PM on the Time Series Insights team.  I think what you're looking for is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/how-to-shape-query-json).  We flatten JSON, and dimension properties are stored alongside telemetry data.

Comment: Hi @ashannon7, the link seems to be regarding how to send events but my question was how to parse the result when retrieving data from the API. We´ve created our own logic to this, but it seems like something that should be a standard, or some guidelines from MS should exist.